# Loading MySQL data to datagridview with existing columns including comboboxes and checkboxes

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm trying to load data to a datagridview (winform project). I have no problems loading "empty" datagridviews but this one has existing columns that contain some textboxes, comboboxes and checkboxes. The columns were created using the designer. I need to load data in these existing columns. The code below loads the data but creates new columns in the datagrid. I don't want that. I need the existing columns to be populated. How can I acheive this? Here is my current code. I'm a newby so if you could help me out with an example it would be great.

```
private void LoadGrid()
    {
        ConnectionStringSettings conSettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["shopmanagerConnectionString1"];
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(conSettings.ToString());
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(@"select cat, operation, location, description, req_met, tol_minus_met, tol_plus_met,req_imp, tol_minus_imp, tol_plus_imp, measurment, tool, external, conform, date_inspected from shopmanager.inspection_reports where products_product_id = @products_product_id;", con);

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@products_product_id", textBox3.Text);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        con.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Your Select statement need to match the existing DGV columns.  You can add "as" to each column to create a mapping between the database and DGV.  For example : @"select cat, operation as OP,

Comment: @jdweng thank you but that did not work. it's adding new columns instead of using the existing ones.

Comment: The mapping is wrong.  See mapping on following webpage : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html

Answer (score 0):

You can make it work in this manual way, and setting `dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;` will help because then your DGV will complain about columns it is trying to find but cant...

..but honesty, you shouldn't be doing any of this this way. It's slow, inefficient, weakly typed and poorly structured. Take a look at the official MSDN tutorial at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxsa23t6.aspx - read the "Creating a Simple Data Application" walkthrough

The steps you'd take would essentially be:

1. add a dataset to the project
2. connect it to your database
3. drop the inspection_reports table into the dataset
4. save, switch to the form
5. drop the inspection_reports node out of the data sources window, onto the form

To customise the query so it filters, right click the generated tableadapter and choose Configure - you'll be able to step through a wizard that lets you parameterize the query. The code inside the form will need a slight adjustment so you pass the contents of textbox3 in as the query parameter

VS will write all the code you have written (and more, reams of it, and better [sorry]) behind the scenes and wire it all up so that you have a grid on the form, with columns that are properly databound etc.. Take about 30 seconds and it'll work right off the bat, be robust, better encapsulated, won't have button click event handlers stuffed full of sql-in-strings..

Please name your controls according to what they do - textBox3 and dataGridView1 are terrible names for controls

Comment: Thank you. I'll go through all this and give it a shot. The problem i'm having is that VS does not want me to create datasets from MySql. I'll try to get that sorted before.

Comment: Might need the ODBC driver/declare your db as an ODBC data source in the "connect it to your database" step

Comment: Hopefully I'll get some time tonight to install mysql and give it a once over. I'll let you know any gotchas I come up against